# Question about radical of a module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

> Let $M$ be a right $A$-module. How to show that $m\in \operatorname{rad}(M)$ iff for any simple right $A$-module $S$ and any $f\in \operatorname{Hom}_A(M, S)$, $f(m)=0$?

I think that if $m$ is in $\operatorname{rad}(M)$, then $m$ is in a maximal submodule $L$ of $M$. If we take $S=M/L$ and $f: M \to M/L$ to be the canonical map, then since $m\in L$ we have $f(m)=0$. But $S$ can be different from $M/L$ and $f$ can be different from the canonical map. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $m$ is annihilated by any $f\in\text{Hom}_A(M,S)$ whenever $S$ is simple. Clearly then $m\in N$ for every maximal module $N$, since $m$ is annihilated by the quotient map $M\to M/N$, and thus in $N$.

Conversely, suppose that $m$ is in $\text{rad}(M)$, $S$ be a simple module, and $f\in\text{Hom}_A(M,S)$. If $f=0$ we're done. If $f\ne 0$, then $f$ is surjective and thus $M/\ker f\cong S$, so that $\ker f$ is maximal, and thus $m\in\ker f$.

Comment: thank you very much. It seems that $ker f$ is maximal.

Comment: @JianrongLi No problem--yeah, that was a typo.