# What is the radical of a representation (as a module of the group ring)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

The radical of an $R$-module $M$ is the intersection of all maximal $R$-submodules of $M$. The radical can equivalently be described as the sum of all superfluous submodules of $M$. A representation $V$ of a group $G$ over a field $k$ can be viewed as a $k[G]$-module.

The radical of $V$ would therefore be the intersection of all maximal subrepresentations of $V$, or equivalently the sum of all superfluous subrepresentations of $V$. If $V$ is irreducible, then <s>$V$ has no subrepresentations so</s> its radical is zero <s>all of $V$ by convention</s>.

Is there a nice description for the radical of $V$ when $V$ is reducible? At the very least, when is it $0$?

Edit: $G$ can be infinite and $V$ can be infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Are these finite dimensional representations? Can $G$ be infinite?

Comment: This is a good question. My answer supposes that all representations are finite-dimensional, but I don't think I require $G$ to be finite, but at least reasonably nice.

Comment: As David's mentioned, the radical of an irreducible representation (aka simple submodule, in my parlance) has a maximal submodule, which is zero, and that is also what the radical is.  In order for $J(M)=M$, you need a module which has no maximal submodules.

Comment: There are groups for which all of $k[G]$'s representations have radical zero. For example, when $k[G]$ is commutative von Neumann regular.  (This would happen for any abelian, locally finite group whose finite subgroups all have orders which are units in $k$.)

Comment: Are you looking for some calculus relating $J(M)$ to $J(R)$?  I'm not really sure how representation theorists think about radicals.  Even restricting to $R=k[G]$ i'm not sure how one would describe $J(M)$ leveraging $k[G]$ at all

Comment: @rschwieb An obvious example for all radicals zero is when $|G|$ is finite and the charatceristic of $k$ doesn't divide $|G|$.

Comment: @rschwieb The representations can be infinite dimensional. $G$ can also be infinite.

Comment: What is your definition of the radical if there are no maximal submodules? For example, an infinite-dimensional vector space with trivial group action.

Comment: My understanding is that the radical is defined to be the entire module if there are no maximal submodules: [see this stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2943977/some-questions-about-radical-of-modules).

Comment: Gah. I hate infinite-dimensional modules. See my edited answer as to why they are horrid.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven thats true. Most precisely it characterized the right V-rings, and the semisimple rings are indeed right and left V.  Thought it would be good to give a big class of commutative examples.

Comment: If people want to do damn fool things like look at infinite-dimensional representations of infinite groups, I will make haste for the hills.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Isn't that what automorphic representations and Langlands program people do for a living?

Comment: Some people run towards the sound of gunfire. I do not.

Answer (score 3):

For this answer $V$ is assumed to be finite-dimensional. Now that the question specifically includes infinite-dimensional modules, it no longer offers a complete answer.

If $V$ is irreducible the radical of $V$ is **zero** by convention, not all of $V$. In fact, this isn't a convention, because zero is a maximal subrepresentation.

A representation has radical zero if and only if it is a direct sum of irreducible representations. This is because the radical of the direct sum of two representations is the direct sum of the radicals.

In general, the radical of a module is non-zero if and only if, whenever one can write the representation as a set of block (upper) triangular matrices, a change of basis yields block diagonal matrices instead.

Thus, morally, the radical is the top-right bit of the representation, that cannot be removed by changing basis.

---

### Edit for infinite-dimensional modules.

Do not look at infinite-dimensional modules. There are modules with no indecomposable summands, for example. There is an infinite-dimensional module $M$ for $G=C_2\times C_2$, over a field of characteristic $2$, such that $M\cong M\oplus M\oplus M$, but $M\not\cong M\oplus M$.

Comment: "superfluous" is the dual to "essential". Some authors prefer the pair "large" and "small". You can't talk about projective covers without superfluous submodules, for example.

Comment: @rschwieb Aha, these terms are from ring theory, a quick Google suggests. They are not used in finite group representation theory.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Sorry for my brainfart, of course the radical would be zero and not all of $V$ when $V$ is irreducible.

Comment: No worries. It happens.